# In LU factorization, can (-1)s appear on L's main diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

My Pearson textbook is showing solutions to "find the LU factorization of the given matrix" problems with (-1)s appearing in L's main diagonal. However when multiplying the two matrices in the solution, it does not return the original given matrix (either wrong signs in the row that has a (-1) or completely incorrect entries. Am I missing something or is this textbook just as shitty as I think it is?

Here's two examples I found in the book:

[image][image][image][image]

I'm getting an LU for 7 as
L =  $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\-3/2&1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$
U =  $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}2&5\\0&7/2\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$
and an LU for 11 as
L =  $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\2&1&0\\-1/3&1&1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$
U =  $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}3&-6&3\\0&5&-4\\0&0&5\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$
When multiplying each respective pair, I get the original given matrix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of LU starts with $L$ as the identity matrix.

Then, after row operations, you get $$L = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -\dfrac{3}{2}& 1\end{bmatrix},~~ U =  \begin{bmatrix} 2 &5 \\ 0 & \dfrac{7}{2} \end{bmatrix}$$

This agrees with your first result.

There is a sign error in your second result (location is $a_{23}$)

$$L = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 2&1&0\\-\dfrac{1}{3} & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}. ~~ U = \begin{bmatrix} 3&-6&3\\ 0&5&-4\\0&0&5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Those are obvious typos in the book solution.

Which book is this? Did you check the errata?

Comment: Thanks for catching the -4 typo. I'm still learning the syntax on this site as well. The book is Linear Algebra and its Applications by David C. Lay / Steven R. Lay. Sadly, there is no errata page in the book.

Comment: It would be an additive list of errors that should be fixed in the next printing, for example: http://www.rrb.wayne.edu/classes/m2250f11/errata.pdf

Comment: @EthanShade: You can right click on a matrix above and see the MathJax code and this is also very handy: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference